# recursive elastic search aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have a mapping whiche stores the level of users. A user might have more than one record, with different levels.

```
user    country     level
a       us          1
a       us          2
b       ca          1
c       us          2
d       ca          2
d       ca          3
e       ja          2
```

For each user, we can get his/her max_level:

```
user    max_level
a       2
b       1
c       2
d       3
e       2
```

then I want to count max_levels:

```
max_level   count
1           1         # b
2           3         # a, c, e
3           1         # d
```

I can get the max level of each user by aggregation like this:

```
"aggs": {
    "user": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "user"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "max_level": {
                "max": {"field": "level"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But how can I perform a bucket aggregation against the above result?

Comment: Your example is not clear. What is the logic behind the `max level, count` table that you provided?

Comment: Hi, @Eli, I have modified the queston.